# Scanner.next() from a BufferedReader

Tags: java

I am trying to scan text from a reader based on a delimiter `"()()"` by using the `Scanner.next()` method. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String buffer = "i want this text()()without this text()()";

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.getBytes());
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
    scan.useDelimiter("/(/)/(/)");
    String found = scan.next();
    System.out.println(found);
}
```

The problem is, the entire buffer is returned:

```
i want this text()()without this text()()
```

I only want the first next() iteration to return:

```
i want this text
```

and the next next() iteration to return:

```
without this text
```

Any suggestions how I can scan the reader by only delimiting strings ending in `()()`?

Comment: Chris, you could do this: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(buffer);` instead of creating all those readers.

Comment: I'm aware. My program uses a BufferedReader.

Answer (score 4):

Your `useDelimiter` argument is incorrect - you're using forward slashes instead of backslashes when you try to escape the parentheses. You need to escape the backslashes in Java terms, too:

```
scan.useDelimiter("\\(\\)\\(\\)");
```

EDIT: Rather than escaping this yourself, you can use [`Pattern.quote`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String rawDelimiter = "()()";
String escaped = Pattern.quote(rawDelimiter);
scan.useDelimiter(escaped);
```

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, you shouldn't up-vote for no reason. You should up-vote if you think the answer is correct.

Comment: [Pattern.escape(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) could also be used for clarity: `String delim = Pattern.escape("()()");`